# How can I get a count of documents in a Firestore collection?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a count of documents in a Firestore collection. I've followed the example given in the Firestore docs but I keep getting a weird result. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't figure out what it is.

Here's the calling code:

```
class GetTransactionsCount extends ConsumerWidget {
  const GetTransactionsCount({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final uid = ref.watch(authStateChangesProvider).value!.uid;
    final auth = ref.watch(authServicesProvider);
    final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    String tCount = db
        .collection('users/$uid/transactions')
        .count()
        .get()
        .then(
          (value) => value.count.toString(),
        )
        .toString();

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(tCount),
        hgap(10),
        Text('transactions'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And here's what I'm getting:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "I keep getting a weird result"?

Comment: See the screenshot; I'm getting "Instance of 'Future<String>' transactions" instead of "148 transactions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the count requires a call to the server and is an asynchronous operation, which means that it returns a `Future`.

To display the value of a `Future` in Flutter, [use a `FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget.

You'll also want to make the widget that you do this in a [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), put the call to Firestore in its [`initState` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html), and make your `tCount` a field of the state.

Answer (score 1):

Getting count from firebase is Future task so, you need to use await or you need to Make text Future Builder like below

```
return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: db
        .collection('users/$uid/transactions')
        .count()
        .get()
        .then(
          (value) => value.count.toString(),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error');
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),

hgap(10),
        Text('transactions'),
      ],
```